# Extract date and time from datetime string in javascript

Tags: javascript

My datetime string is of below format:

```
var sdt = '2022-05-19T13:00:00';
```

I want to extract the date and time separately and below is my code:

```
((sdt.getMonth() > 8) ? (sdt.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (sdt.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((sdt.getDate() > 9) ? sdt.getDate() : ('0' + sdt.getDate())) + '/' + sdt.getFullYear() + ' ' + (sdt.getHours()) + ':' + (sdt.getMinutes()) + ':00'
```

From the above code, date is getting extracted correctly but not the time. any help pls?

Comment: Can you the desire result you want ?

Comment: You must first convert string into datetime format, using `var sdt = new Date('2022-05-19T13:00:00');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and use [Date#toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) & [Date#toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) method to get your time and date

Or even the [Date#toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to get both at the same time !

```js
const sdt = '2022-05-19T13:00:00';
const date = new Date(sdt)

console.log(date.toLocaleString())

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString())
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString())
```

Note that you can specify the location to get the date for a current country

```js
date.toLocaleString('en-GB')
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor:

```
const sdtString = '2022-05-19T13:00:00'; // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
const sdt = new Date(sdtString); // Date Object {}
```

then to get the respective date / time use:

- [Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)
- [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Also, worth remembering that `getMonth()` gives the month's **index** (zero based), not the number.

Answer (score 1):

I always use a moment.js when dealing with date and time .
Just pass the datetime string and specify the format of the output you want .

```
import moment from 'moment'

var sdt = '2022-05-19T13:00:00';

let time = moment(sdt).format("HH:mm:ss")
let date = moment(sdt).format("DD/MM/YYYY")

console.log(time)  //01:00:00
console.log(date) //19/05/2022
```

https://momentjs.com/ checkout this page to learn about more formats

Comment: Can you imagine loading js code of above 50kB just for this? See other answers, just "few" bytes more then OP question.

Comment: @nelek Well said , I think if the size is an issue probably using js Date is a good option , If its a big project where you work a lot with time and date , moment.js is the best option yet.